# Swift - should I create local variable of a strings "count"?

Tags: swift, string, count, swift5

Does it matter if I use a strings 'count' multiple times within a function. That is, does Swift cache the 'count' after it firsts computes it. Below are two examples, does it matter which one I use? I assume the second is definitely okay but what about the first? I see example code like the first one all the time.

```
func Foo1 (str: String) {
...
// calling str.count twice
if x < str.count && y < str.count {
...
}

func Foo2 (str: String) {
...
// calling str.count once
let c = str.count
if x < c && y < c {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.count` is defined by the `Collection` protocol with the following complexity:

> Complexity: O(1) if the collection conforms to RandomAccessCollection; otherwise, O(n), where n is the length of the collection.

String is not a RandomAccessCollection. It's a BidirectionalCollection, so it does not promise O(1). It only promises O(n).

It definitely does not promise any caching (and you shouldn't expect any).

It happens to be true that in many (probably most) cases, String's count is cached. It's part of `_StringObject`, which is part of the low-level storage abstraction, and it's often inlined by the optimizer. But none of this is promised.

That said, unless you expect the String to be extremely large (10kB at a minimum, possibly more), it is difficult to imagine this being a major bottleneck by being called twice outside a tight loop. As with most things, you should write clearly, and then profile. I would likely create an extra variable just for clarity, but you shouldn't second-guess here too much. Write clearly. Then profile.

Do you have particularly large strings that you're working with?

Comment: Even if not cached explicitly in the implementation, I would be surprised (disappointed), if the compiler couldn't infer the const-ness of an unmutated string, and reuses the value itself. But as you say, it's not something that you can rely on if it's important to your use case.

Comment: Very nice description Rob. I had the same exact thoughts and use a second variable all the time. But I see many examples even from Apple making multiple calls I figured maybe I'm missing something. Thanks!